# canvas draw circle with quadratic curve

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I know I can draw arc with `arc` function of canvas but when I increase the size of that arc it changes its start and end x,y points. So I was thinking if we can draw arc with some other way keeping its start end points fixed while increasing it size.

**Edit**
Below is the images showing what I am looking for. First image shows a rectangle. when its side is stretched it changed to circle(2nd image). when side is stretched further it changed to big circle. At in all images you can see that end points of circle are joined to corners of rectangle. This is what I want to do.

[image]

**1st Image**

[image]

**2nd Image**

[image]

**3rd Image**

Or you can see [**this video**](http://youtu.be/rJGTDUVJ0NU) to understand what I am looking to do.

**What I have done**
This [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepthakurala/g8dgp/1/embedded/result/) shows result of my work.
To draw rectangle just click and drag your mouse.

[`Here is the code`](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepthakurala/g8dgp/1)

Comment: What do you mean with it changes start and end points? Can you show a picture of the problem? With "size" do you mean thickness?

Comment: @6502: I mean if we keep start & end point fixed and increase the size of arc then it will look more like a semi circle

Comment: @6502: like in quadratic curve when we increase its size, location of end points remain same.

Comment: About that bounty, what exactly do you mean with "The current answers do not contain enough detail."?

Comment: Look, if you're not going to explain why the answer's not good enough, we can't help you.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Your answer does helped a bit but it is not actually I wanted. Please see the video. You are drawing a circle and then removing some of its portion but my requirement is dynamic i.e user will draw a rectangle or a square and he can drag any side of it, more user will drag side more bigger will be the circle. I tried your code but circle is not staying on the starting points which is primary requirement.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
draw(0);
$('#range').on('change', function(){
    range = parseInt($(this).val());
    draw(range)
})

function draw(val){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    x = 100,
    y = 50,
    d;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(val,2) + Math.pow(50,2));

    context.beginPath();
    context.lineWidth = 1;

    context.arc(x,y+val,d,0,2*Math.PI);

    // line color
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
    context.stroke();

    // Cut off the top of the circle.
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, y);

    // This stuff's just to show some dots
    context.fillStyle = 'red';
    context.fillRect(x-1,y-1,2,2); // Middle
    context.fillRect(x-52,y-2,4,4);//Target point 1
    context.fillRect(x+48,y-2,4,4);// Target point 2

    context.fillRect(x-2,y+d+val-2,4,4); // Point on circle
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
}
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/C7yBd/3/)**

There are a couple disadvantages to this is that it gets "slower" the closer you get to the circle, because the circle's getting exponentially larger in the hidden section (The slider's controlling it's size), and that it doesn't work for diagonal lines as it is right now.

Other than that, it works like expected.

Answer (score 2):

Check this : http://jsfiddle.net/KZBzq/4/

Updated answer with **bezierCurveTo**

**HTML**

```
<label>Range :</label>
<input type="range" name="points" value="0" min="0" step="1" max="100" id="range"> 
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="250"></canvas>
```

**JS**

```
draw(100); 

$('#range').on('change', function(){
  range = parseInt($(this).val());
  draw(100-range)
})

function draw(val){

  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  x = 100,
  y = 100,
  cp1x = x/2,
  cp2x = y/2,
  cp1y = val,
  cp2y = val;
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  context.beginPath();
  context.lineWidth = 1;

  context.moveTo(25 , x);
  context.bezierCurveTo(cp1x,cp1y,cp2x,cp2y,x,y);

    // line color
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
    context.stroke();

}
```

Now x and Y are fixed. Is this was your requirement?

Comment: I know I can do thins with arc function. I am looking for some other way.